# Are Leaflet extensions plugins compatible with TomTom web SDK?

Tags: leaflet, sdk

TomTom in their developer site says:
[image]

Does this mean that Leaflet extensions and plugins are also compatible with their SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. Instead of `L.---` you have to use `tt.---`